# Need help on Android Bluedroid stack

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

We have a android phone connecting with an embedded board(running Android) via Bluetooth.we can play audio using the android phone through A2DP.We also want to run an application on this phone to send some data to the board using BLE(GATT) at the same time.But when we run this application,the A2DP sink will be disconnected and the audio will be stoped playing.So we can not do the two things simultaneously.

Do you have any idea on what is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: A2DP is only in Classic Bluetooth (not BLE) so maybe your embedded board has a dual stack (Classic + LE) but it can't use them both at the same time or a configuration needed on the board to enable simultaneous connections from the two stacks

Comment: @Tomer, we do have a dual stack, but we could not use it at the same time.
we do not know whether it is a hardware problem or software problem.

Comment: Can you please specify the company and the model of the board?

Comment: https://www.variscite.com/product/system-on-module-som/cortex-a53-krait/dart-sd410-qualcomm-snapdragon-410/

This is the board we are using now.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a configuration issue or by design. According to the data sheet the connectivity module is WCN3620 and when looking at its data sheet, see [here](https://developer.qualcomm.com/qfile/29369/lm80-p0436-33_b_wcn3620_wireless_connectivity_ic_device_spec.pdf) page 34 you can see there are 3 BT modes - I didn't see any configuration regrading using two modes simultaneously but I would double check with the vendor.

Comment: @TomerPetel,thank you!